# Want to confine termios defines and others in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I know it is very simple but after a couple of hours I couldn't resolve it by my self.
I have included `termios.h` in the `.h` of my class and now, most of `#defines` inside termios interfere with my variable names (they are same names!) so I have compiling errors.
Is there a correct way to put `termios.h` inside a namespace? then using it only where need it?

thank you very much

```
#include termios.h
class MyClass {
public:
bool B50;  // it interfere with #define  B50    0000001 in bits/termios.h
bool B100;
bool B200; // this too
private:
void _process();
...
}
```

Comment: what is the output of the compiler? please list the errors.

Comment: sas.h:136: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
                 bool B50;
code I paste above is simplified. If I do not include termios, there is no error at all. If I look into termios.h I found a #define B50 and a lot of other definitions that may interfere then with my code.